# Командная строка внутри VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

В IntelliJ IDEA мне понравилось, что командная строка находится внутри IDE, а не выскакивает отдельное окно cmd. Так же мне понравилась возможность ввода данных вставкой столбца нужных данных. В VS мне приходится вводить каждое значение отдельно.
Можно ли настроить VS так, чтобы в ней был такой терминал?

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно, если посавить в свойствах проекта тип Windows Application вместо Console application. Консоль cmd больше не будет открываться.

Зачем поставить галочку тут диалог Options -> Debugging -> "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window"

Теперь весь output будет писаться в окно output при дегабе. Однако вводить текст с клавы в него не получится.